# Force OpenWindow to use absolute path without http

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that needs to open a shared file location in a new tab to download it. The file location is in the form of:
`\\myserver\myfolder\file.doc\`

However, when I use

```
window.open("\\myserver\myfolder\file.doc", "_blank");
```

It just appends the path to my current url. I know I can force an absolute path by adding `https:` to the prefix of my url, but if I do this, I cannot access the shared file. Is there any other way to open a new tab using the url I specified as an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `file://`. Prefix your current path with `file://` and it should open correctly. This is sort of like specifying the protocol you are using.

```
window.open("file:///myserver/myfolder/file.doc", "_blank");
```

1. The third slash represents the root of your file system (like "\").
2. Since it is a path in a url, forward slashes are used

Comment: I tried your changes, but it is still appending to my current url. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I have tested this and it works for me. What does your current url look like (the page that you are running the `window.open` code in.)

Comment: whoops, sorry about that - I forgot to add the colon. Working great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
window.open('file://{path_to_your_file}', '_blank')
```